# T-SQL language specification and lexing rules

Tags: sql, t-sql, code-generation, lexical-analysis

I'm thinking about writing a templating tool for generating T-SQL code, which will include delimited sections like below;

```
SELECT 
    ~~idcolumn~~
FROM
    ~~table~~
WHERE
    ~~table~~.flag = 1
```

Notice the double-tildes delimiting bits? This is an idea for an escape sequence in my templating language. But I want to be certain that the escape sequence is valid -- that it will never occur in a valid T-SQL statement. Problem is, I can't find any official microsoft description of the T-SQL language.

Does anyone know of an official specification for the T-SQL language, or at least the lexing rules? So I can make an informed decision about the escape sequence.

**UPDATES:**

Thanks for the suggestions so far, but I'm not looking for confirmation of the '~~' escape sequence *per se*. What I need is a document I can reference I can point to and say 'microsoft says this character sequence is totally impossible in T-SQL.' For instance, microsoft publish the language specification for C# [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm) which includes a description of what characters can go into valid C# programs. (see page 67 of the pdf.) I'm looking for a similar reference.

**The double-tilde:** "~~" is actually perfectly good T-SQL. For instance; "(SELECT ~~1)" returns '1'.

Answer (score 1):

There are several well known and often used formats for template parameters, one example being `$(paramname)` (also used in other scripts as well as T-SQL scripts)

Why not use an existing format?

Comment: Looks like reinventing a commodity wheel to me.

Comment: @le dorfier : Hi, I'm not sure what a commodity wheel is?

Comment: As you say, $(val) is the SQLCMD parameter format. The language I'm writing will involve more than single-value replacement, though; there will be a whole small language inside the escaped parts, with loops, conditionals, etc. So the terminating ')' may not be 'strong' enough, in that it could well occur in my own language. '$( expr )$' might be fine, though.

Comment: @le dorfier; I can see how it would look like that. What I'm actually looking for is a microsoft guarantee that whatever I choose is valid -- well, actually it has to be *invaldi* T-SQL. I just chucked the ~~ in as an example.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter if ~~ is legal TSQL or not, if you provide an escape for producing ~~ in actual TSQL when you need it.

Since template parameters have to have a nonzero-length identifier, you have a peculiar case where the identifier length is ridiculously "zero", e.g., ~~~~.  This kind of thing makes an ideal escape sequence, since it is useless for anything else.   Simply process your template text; whenever you find ~~~~ replace it by the named parameter string, and whenever you find ~~~~ replace it by ~~.  Now, if ~~ is needed in the final TSQL, just write ~~~~ in your template.

I suspect that even if you do this, that the number of times you'll actually write ~~~~ in practice will be close to zero, so the reason for doing it is theoretical completeness and giving you a warm fuzzy feeling that you can write anything in a template.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure about a complete description of the language, but it appears that `~~` could occur in an [identifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx) provided that it is quoted (in brackets, typically).

You may have more luck with a convention saying you don't support identifiers with `~~` in them.  Or, just reserve your own lexical symbols and don't worry about `~~` occurring elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you'll find something that will **never** occur in a valid statement.  Consider:

`DECLARE @TemplateBreakingString varchar(100) = '~~I hope this works~~'`

or

`CREATE TABLE [~~TemplateBreakingTable~~] (IDField INT Identity)`

Answer (score 0):

You could treat quoted literals and strings as content, regardless if they contain your escape-sequence. It would make it more robust.

Run the text trough a lexer, to separate each token. If the token is a string or a quoted literal, treat it as such. But if it is a literal that begins and ends with `~~`, you can safely assume it is a template placeholder.

Answer (score -1):

Your escape sequence can occur in string literals, but that is all.  That said, Microsoft owns t-sql, and they are free to do anything they want with it moving forward for future versions of sql server.  Still, I think ~~ is safe enough.

Comment: ~ is actually bitwise NOT, which makes ~~ the identity operator for integers. It's actually perfectly valid; eg '(SELECT ~~1)' => 1. this is why I want documentary evidence I can use for the right choice. I'm only looking to guarantee T-SQL for SQL Server 2005 to 2008r2.